# Android Background Task and Battery consumption

Tags: android, react-native, background-task

I'm having an app that would execute a background-task **every-hour**

The background task would simply check if a certain condition is met ... and if yes, it will show up notification. It doesn't need an-internet connection as well.

I'm developing through a bridge (**React Native**) ... So I'm really not sure if `WorkManager` is supported

My question is: does running a simple background-task every-hour is battery-consuming ? Is there any tool to check my app against battery-consumption ?

Comment: "does running a simple background-task every-hour is battery-consuming ?" -- if you use APIs like `WorkManager`, no. It will consume battery when it is actually doing the work, but it will not consume battery otherwise.

Comment: I'm actually developing through a bridge (React-Native App) ... it uses something called `Headless JS to run tasks in JavaScript while your app is in the background` ... Im not sure if it uses `WorkManager` in the background

Comment: Use [work manager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) . You can also restrict access for example where there is no internet, save batery etc